# Could not find asset using Polymer.Dart

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I went through the introductory tutorial for Dart and Polymer individually, and now trying to play with Polymer-Dart. All samples are using custom element, but none of them are using core-elements, hence the confusion.

**EDIT** : I have edited code and added more details as per suggestions in comments.

Here is the console output :

```
[web] GET /packages/core_elements/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html => Could not find asset core_elements|lib/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html.
[web] GET /packages/core_elements/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html => Could not find asset core_elements|lib/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html.
[web] GET /packages/paper_elements/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html => Could not find asset paper_elements|lib/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html.
```

Tools output :

```
[Warning from polymer (Linter) on mini|web/mini.html]:
web/mini.html:12:5: couldn't find imported asset "lib/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html" in package "core_elements".
[Warning from polymer (Linter) on mini|web/mini.html]:
web/mini.html:13:5: couldn't find imported asset "lib/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html" in package "core_elements".
[Warning from polymer (Linter) on mini|web/mini.html]:
web/mini.html:14:5: couldn't find imported asset "lib/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html" in package "paper_elements".
[Warning from polymer (Linter) on mini|web/mini.html]:
web/mini.html:26:6: definition for Polymer element with tag name "paper-input" not found.
[Warning from polymer (Linter) on mini|web/mini.html]:
web/mini.html:29:4: definition for Polymer element with tag name "core-header-panel" not found.
[Warning from polymer (Linter) on mini|web/mini.html]:
web/mini.html:31:5: definition for Polymer element with tag name "core-toolbar" not found.
[Warning from polymer (Linter) on mini|web/mini.html]:
web/mini.html:34:5: definition for Polymer element with tag name "paper-tabs" not found.
[Warning from polymer (Linter) on mini|web/mini.html]:
web/mini.html:35:7: definition for Polymer element with tag name "paper-tab" not found.
[Warning from polymer (Linter) on mini|web/mini.html]:
web/mini.html:36:7: definition for Polymer element with tag name "paper-tab" not found.
Build error:
Transform ImportInliner on mini|web/mini.html threw error: Could not find asset core_elements|lib/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html.
null
null
Build completed with 1 errors.
```

pubsec.yaml

```
name: mini
description: A sample web application
dependencies:
    polymer: ">=0.11.0 <0.12.0"
    core_elements: ">=0.0.6 <0.1.0"
    paper_elements: ">=0.0.1 <0.1.0"
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/mini.html
```

mini.dart :

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {

}

void reverseText(MouseEvent event) {
  var text = querySelector("#sample_text_id").text;
  var buffer = new StringBuffer();
  for (int i = text.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    buffer.write(text[i]);
  }
  querySelector("#sample_text_id").text = buffer.toString();
}
```

mini.html :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Mini</title>

    <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
         not necessary anymore with Polymer >= 0.14.0 -->

    <link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">

    <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>    
    <script async src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mini.css">

  </head>
  <body unresolved touch-action="auto">
    <h1>TODO list</h1>

   <div>
     <paper-input label="Your Name"></paper-input>
   </div>

   <core-header-panel>

    <core-toolbar>
    </core-toolbar>

    <paper-tabs id="tabs" selected="all" self-end>
      <paper-tab name="all">ALL</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab name="favorites">FAVORITES</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>

  </core-header-panel>

  </body>
</html>
```

I am able to build successfully, and I have ensured all these components are there in packages (with correct names and paths)

Comment: Can you post your complete .HTML and .dart file as well as your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes a difference but I always hat `dart_support.js` and `platform.js` **before** the element imports and `mini.dart` and `dart.js` **after** the element imports.
You are sure that the `Tools Output` window in DartEditor doesn't print any warnings? There are often warnings at the beginning of the output and after that an awful lot of logging output from pub serve which disguises previous warning output.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: Thanks, I saw some errors in Tools Output. But I get them even after changing code per your suggestion. I dont know why Dart is searching for polymer in /lib - shouldn't it search in the packages automatically ? Am I supposed to copy everything to lib ?

Comment: The files from imported packages are always in `lib` but you don't include the `lib` part in your import path. You don't have to copy anything. I yet have to check but I'm pretty sure the problem are the `-` (dash) in the imported file names. As far as I know they are `_` (underline) in Dart because this is the official file name convention for Dart files.
I just checked. The import paths and file names must correspond to files listed here https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/tree/master/lib.
This files only have underscores and no dashes (in contrast to Polymer.js core-elements)

Comment: You can also check the file names in DartEditor by expanding the `packages` directory in your Dart application directory. Here you get the content of the packages `lib` directory listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
<!-- before the Polymer elements imports -->
<script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
     not necessary anymore with Polymer >= 0.14.0 -->

<!-- Dart core-elements/paper-elements use underscores not dashes in the file names -->
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_header_panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_tabs.html">

<!-- after the Polymer elements imports -->
<script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>    
<script async src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
```

Comment: The path in "packages" directory was : core_elements/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html. That is not working. I changed it to all underscores, still the same error. I think the problem is that it is searching for a lib folder, but I dont have one. Should I create a lib folder, and add all packages content there ?

Comment: As stated above - you don't need to create a `lib` directory or copy something to `lib`. The files listed below `packages/somepackage` are actually `packages/somepackage/lib` but Dart doesn't show `lib` but it is implicitely.
This is another difference to the JavaScript elements - in paper_elements and core_elements there are no subdirectories for each element. The files to import are all directly in `lib`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your problem:

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
```

Although the HTML elements use a `-` character, the file and directory names use `_`.
So your imports have to be:

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_header_panel/core_header_panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_toolbar/core_toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_tabs/paper_tabs.html">
```

Comment: The path in "packages" directory was : core_elements/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html. That is not working. I changed it to all underscores, still the same error. I think the problem is that it is searching for a lib folder, but I dont have one. Should I create a lib folder, and add all packages content there ?